# Send binary file (Excel file) to browser in CakePHP 3.3

Tags: excel, file, cakephp, download, send

I have a method that tries to send an xlsx (Excel 2007) file that exists on the server. The xlsx file is ok, I can open it (locally) from the server.

But when the file is downloaded from the client side, it gets corrupted. Here is the method:

```
    public function exportToExcel()
    {
        $fileName = ROOT . '/files/xls' . DS . 'assessors.xlsx';

        $this->autoRender = false;

        $assessors = $this->StaAssessors->find('all');

        $this->Utils->exportToExcel( $fileName, $assessors );

        $this->response->type('xlsx');

        $this->response->file( $fileName, ['download' => true ] );

        return( $this->response );
    }
```

I guess the problem is that the excel file is compressed, and my method somewhat can not handle correctly the binary file to be sent to the browser.

Below I've attached the headers as they are received by the browser.

[image]

Is there any thing that I am missing?

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging (and show the results), without further information, all people can do is shooting in the dark, which is not very helpful. What headers are being sent when requesting the file (check your browsers network console)? How exactly does the downloaded content differ from the content on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it adding ob_clean() before returning the $this->response.

Comment: If that makes your problem go away, then you're just hiding the actual problem, which is that there is data being output before the response is being sent to the browser. You should try to find out where that happens and fix the problem at its core.

Comment: thanks fot the tip.  I will do further investigation.